# jenkins pipeline input via email

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins pipeline 
I want user to give input via email 
I tried this but didnt helped.

```
def tok = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
mail to: 'admins@mycorp', subject: 'Ready to roll?', mimeType: 'text/html',
body: """Please <a href="${env.JENKINS_URL}pipeline-inputs/${tok}/proceed">approve me</a>!"""
input message: 'Ready?', token: tok
```

Any pointer about this, I want token or any type of authentication also.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried submitting the request e.g. with `curl` or Postman? Is maybe a POST request needed?

Answer (score 6):

```
        emailext mimeType: 'text/html',
                 subject: "[Jenkins]${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
                 to: "tom@xxx.com",
                 body: '''<a href="${BUILD_URL}input">click to approve</a>'''

        def userInput = input id: 'userInput',
                              message: 'Let\'s promote?', 
                              submitterParameter: 'submitter',
                              submitter: 'tom',
                              parameters: [
                                [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'sit', description: 'Environment', name: 'env'],
                                [$class: 'TextParameterDefinition', defaultValue: 'k8s', description: 'Target', name: 'target']]

        echo ("Env: "+userInput['env'])
        echo ("Target: "+userInput['target'])
        echo ("submitted by: "+userInput['submitter'])
```

Tom will receive a mail containing the input url, and only tom can submit the input successfully.

Comment: "Error you need to be tom to submit this." what should be the value that submitter should match with?

Comment: FOUND IT!tom is the username used to login to jenkins. Thanks