# Jenkins Manual email approval before deployment

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to build a logic for our UAT team to deploy code only upon approval from manager . I would like to know how can be achieved ? Email approval ?. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
//this will grab user - who is running the job
def user
node {
  wrap([$class: 'BuildUser']) {
    user = env.BUILD_USER_ID
  }
  
  emailext mimeType: 'text/html',
                 subject: "[Jenkins]${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}",
                 to: "user@xxx.com",
                 body: '''<a href="${BUILD_URL}input">click to approve</a>'''
}

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('deploy') {
            input {
                message "Should we continue?"
                ok "Yes"
            }
            when {
                expression { user == 'hardCodeApproverJenkinsId'}
            }
            steps {
                sh "echo 'describe your deployment' "
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you can also get some more help from this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310573/jenkins-pipeline-input-via-email)  question

Comment: On top of approval I have scenario where there are two deploy stages ( two different environment deployments).. but approver wants one environment to be deployed immediately and another one after few hours of delay . How can we achieve it ?

Comment: instide `stages {}` you can add as many stage you want , before or after - [Jenkins declarative syntex] (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#pipeline-syntax) will help you how to.
if this helps you, please accept the answer, so that others will get benefits from it.

Comment: @SamitKumarPatel bhai, I written same code in jenkins but getting this error : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367117/java-lang-unsupportedoperationexception-no-known-implementation-of-class-jenkin  can you please help for same ?

Comment: BuildUser class comes with - ‘build-user-vars-plugins’ plugins. Install it , it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified and made to work like this. Here, email will be triggered before running further stages. Also for timeout is set for email approval or console approval.

```
    def deployBranch=""
    def deployService=""
    pipeline {
    agent { node { label '*****' } }
        stages {
            stage('configure'){
                steps{
                    script{
                    env.deployBranch = sh(script:'''echo $branch''', returnStdout: true).trim()
                    env.deployService = sh(script:'''echo $service''', returnStdout: true).trim()
                    echo """${env.deployBranch}"""
                    }
                }
            }
            stage ('checkout-NonMaster') {
                when {
                    not {
                        environment(name: "deployBranch", value: "master")
                    }
                }
                steps {
                    emailext    subject: """<you can send branch and service name for information to approve>""",
                                body: '''<a href="${BUILD_URL}input">click to approve</a>''',
                                to: 'xyz@xyz.com',
                                mimeType: 'text/html' 
                    script {
                        def Delay = input id: 'Deploy',
                            message: sh(script:'''echo "You are DEPLOYING -->$branch<-- IN PRODUCTION"''', returnStdout: true).trim(),
                            submitter: 'uaserID1, userID2',
                            parameters: [
                                    [$class: 'ChoiceParameterDefinition',
                                     choices: ['no','yes'].join('\n'),
                                     name: 'input',
                                     description: 'Please Select "YES" to Build or "NO" to Abort']
                            ]
                            echo "The answer is: ${Delay}"
                            if( "${Delay}" == "yes"){
                            sh'''echo "Deploying in prod"'''
                            } else {
                            sh """
                            echo "exiting not production ready branch"
                            exit 1
                            """
                            }
                    }
                        <anything goes here like groovy code or shell commands>
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).